# How to connect to Access 97 database with Java using OLEDB4.0?

Tags: java, c#, database, ms-access, oledb

i'm using a windows 64 bits and i have managed to connect to newer Access dataBases using ucanaccess api (http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html), which connects alright. The problem is that i need to open an Access 97 database and the API does not support it.

If i use a jdbc:odbc like this:

```
 Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=myDB.mdb");
```

It doest not work aswell. It only works with newer access database and not the access 97 version.

I have managed to access it in C# using this provider:

```
OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\\camiones.mdb");
        connect.Open();
```

It worked the way i expected but i need to open it using java and i do not want to use JNI for this and i can't upgrade the database.

Any suggestion on this? Can i use a Jet OLEDB connection in Java to solve my problem? I have been doing lots of research and haven't found a way to solve this yet, i would appreaciate any help.

Thank you,

Comment: access 97? almost 20 years ago, you should update it.

Comment: "i need to open it using java and i do not want to use JNI for this and i can't upgrade the database" - Then you're screwed.

Comment: UCanAccess supports Access 97 format in read-only. I've fixed some issues about  Access 97 in the 2.0.6 , so I suggest to try this version (if you need a read-only connection).